# flexbox transitions without javascript

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, flexbox

I am trying to add transitions to a responsive nav with flexbox properties.
When the window reduce, the last li element go down and grow.

Can I do the li element that go down gradually grows without using javascript, only css transitions?

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style: none;
    align-content: space-between;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    transition: all 400ms linear;
}

nav ul li {
    background: #ccc;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <title>Menú Flexbox</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>logo</li>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>interior</li>
            <li>innovation</li>
            <li>about us</li>
            <li>countact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

It could be possible using media-queries?

Comment: The problem is that only the used value of `width` changes, but not the specified value, so just adding a transition of `width` won't work. You could try changing the specified value, but you would need a way to detect when the element is moved to the next line. I don't think you can do that with CSS alone.

Comment: Indeed, CSS can't "detect" wrapping or line breaks. JS would be required.